# Como tirar o AM de uma data que não segue um padrão?

Tags: sql, oracle

Minha data vem nesse formato:
3/1/2020 12:00:00 AM 
(Percebe que não é 01 e 03, é apenas 1 e 3)
Mas, obviamente, também pode vir com dois números no dia e mês. Ex: 10/10/2020
Isso torna mais difícil em pensar em cortar a string, e acredito que seria muita gambiarra.
Procurei como transformar Datetime em Date e vi que eles cortavam, oq seria mais difícil pra mim com esse problema de 1 ou 2 números.

Queria saber como rancar isso fora, ou ao menos lidar com ele igual eu lidei com o tempo, simplesmente deixei o tempo alí e coloquei o "HH24:MI:SS".

Minha parte da query tá assim:

```
...AND  dat_inspecao_programada >= TO_DATE('3/1/2020 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')...
```

Comment: Não fica difícil cortar a string não, só dar um split por /

Comment: Em Oracle isso?

Comment: Sim, em Oracle.
Cheguei a uma solução, converti para string cortando o final usando o c#.
Mas tô com outro problema: Devia funcionar, mas não tá funfando.
O que será que aconteceu?
Agora tá assim:



... AND  dat_inspecao_programada >= TO_DATE('01 March 2020', 'DD MM YYYY');



Aparece o erro:



"ORA-01841: ano (completo) deve estar entre -4713 e +9999 e não pode ser zero
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range"

Answer (score 0):

Veja se uma dessas soluções resolve.

Converter com o AM/PM:

```
TO_DATE('3/1/2020 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS am', 'nls_date_language=american')
```

Converter com mês por escrito:

```
TO_DATE('01 March 2020', 'DD MONTH YYYY', 'nls_date_language=american')
```